# Basic RMI using netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, rmi

I am staring to learn about RMI in java and I am using Netbeans 7.0.1. I created a basic interface

```
package helloclass;
import java.rmi.*;

public interface HelloInterface extends Remote
{
    public String hello() throws RemoteException;

}
```

This is the class that implements the interface

```
package helloclass;
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;


public class HelloClass extends UnicastRemoteObject implements HelloInterface
{
    private String message;
    public HelloClass() throws RemoteException{}//constructor throwing RemoteException

    public String hello() throws RemoteException //method throwing RemoteException
    {
        return "Saying hello";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {



    }
}
```

In my understanding I now need to build these two classes and then run the `rmic` command in the command prompt.

How do I run this `rmic` command in the command prompt using netbeans?.
I have been trying by going to Project Properties and then typing `rmic` in the VM options at the Run after specifying the directory where `HelloClass.class` is located but it can't seem to find the class.

Comment: good morning for whom? maybe it's evening here, how do you know :)  ?

Comment: This might be what you want: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/implementing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Java 5 there is no need to use the `rmic` command for generating stubs, they will be generated dynamically for you, check [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/rmi/relnotes.html)

However, if you still want to support clients running on earlier version, run the command from the base directory of the compiled classes (in your case the directory that contains the "helloclass" directory) and use the class qualified name, e.g.: `rmic helloclass.HelloClass`

Comment: This is true as long as you cite a port number when super()-ing/exporting. If you use one of the super()/exportObject() overloads without a port parameter, they are constrained to construct an `rmic`-generated stub, as discussed in the Javadoc preamble to `UnicastRemoteObject`.